# CommunicationException raised when returning an EF4 POCO from WCF service operation

Tags: c#, wcf, entity-framework-4, ef-code-first

The following code raises a *System.ServiceModel.CommunicationException*. It's calling a WCF service operation called *Login* which returns an EF4 POCO:

```
        var client = new AuthServiceReference.AuthServiceClient();

        try
        {
            Console.Write("Trying to logon...");
            var session = client.Login("user", "password"); // throws CommunicationException
            Console.WriteLine("done!");
            Console.WriteLine("Session ID: {0}. Expires {1}", 
                session.Id, session.UtcExpires.ToLocalTime());
        }
        finally
        {
            client.Close();
        }
```

I've been debugging & searching for hours trying to find out **why** this happens & how to fix it. What I've found so far:

1. This is probably a serialization issue
2. When I remove the *DataMemberAttribute* from the *Session* class's *Owner* member, the exception disappears, but this means it won't be serialized.

I'd be grateful if anyone could shed some light on this issue.

Below is the code for the service contract & POCO classes:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IAuthService
{
    [OperationContract]
    Session Login(string username, string passwordHash);

    [OperationContract]
    void Logout(Guid sessionId);
}

[DataContract]
public class Session
{
    [DataMember]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public DateTime UtcCreated { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public DateTime UtcExpires { get; set; }

    [DataMember] // serializes correctly if commented out
    public virtual User Owner { get; set; }

    public static Session Create(User owner)
    {
        return new Session
        {
            Owner = owner,
            Id = Guid.NewGuid(),
            UtcCreated = DateTime.UtcNow,
            UtcExpires = DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(1)
        };
    }
}

[DataContract]
public class User
{
    [DataMember]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string PasswordHash { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string PasswordSalt { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public bool IsContributor { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public bool IsConfirmed { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public bool IsAdmin { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public virtual ICollection<Post> Posts { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public virtual ICollection<Comment> Comments { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out this is a known issue when serializing POCO proxies with WCF. There's an [MSDN walkthough](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee705457.aspx) that explains how to work around it using *System.Data.Objects.ProxyDataContractResolver*.

Essentially, you create a new class called *ApplyDataContractResolverAttribute* and apply it to the service methods returning POCOS:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IAuthService
{
    [OperationContract]
    [ApplyDataContractResolver]
    Session Login(string username, string passwordHash);
}
```

---

```
using System;
using System.Data.Objects;
using System.ServiceModel.Channels;
using System.ServiceModel.Description;
using System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher;

namespace WcfExampleBlog.Services
{
    public class ApplyDataContractResolverAttribute : Attribute, IOperationBehavior
    {
        #region IOperationBehavior Members

        public void AddBindingParameters(OperationDescription description, BindingParameterCollection parameters)
        {
        }

        public void ApplyClientBehavior(OperationDescription description, ClientOperation proxy)
        {
            var dataContractSerializerOperationBehavior =
                description.Behaviors.Find<DataContractSerializerOperationBehavior>();
            dataContractSerializerOperationBehavior.DataContractResolver =
                new ProxyDataContractResolver();
        }

        public void ApplyDispatchBehavior(OperationDescription description, DispatchOperation dispatch)
        {
            var dataContractSerializerOperationBehavior =
                description.Behaviors.Find<DataContractSerializerOperationBehavior>();
            dataContractSerializerOperationBehavior.DataContractResolver =
                new ProxyDataContractResolver();
        }

        public void Validate(OperationDescription description)
        {
            // Do validation.
        }

        #endregion
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am presuming that the 'User' class is a custom class? If so, you need to add this just below the ServiceContract attribute:

```
[KnownType(typeof(User))]
```

You would also need to setup your [DataMember] and [ServiceContract] attributes on the User class as well.

Comment: The User class is shown in my question (below the Session class). It's also decorated with a DataContractAttribute. I'll try adding the KnownTypeAttribute